# Elasticsearch: rewrite a query using java native api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have this query in Elasticsearch that is working perfectly if I run it from the command line:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX_NAME/_search/
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "autocomplete",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "include": {
          "pattern": "c.*"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "autocomplete": {
        "value": "c"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to rewrite it in java using the native client:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse2 = newClient.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery("{\n" +
                "  \"size\": 0,\n" +
                "  \"aggs\": {\n" +
                "    \"autocomplete\": {\n" +
                "      \"terms\": {\n" +
                "        \"field\": \"autocomplete\",\n" +
                "        \"order\": {\n" +
                "          \"_count\": \"desc\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        \"include\": {\n" +
                "          \"pattern\": \"c.*\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"query\": {\n" +
                "    \"prefix\": {\n" +
                "      \"autocomplete\": {\n" +
                "        \"value\": \"c\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}").get();
        for (SearchHit res : searchResponse2.getHits()){
            System.out.println(res.getSourceAsString());

        }
```

Seems, that I'm missing something in this translation process. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Java client `setQuery()` method doesn't take a String with the JSON query, you need to [build the query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html) using the `QueryBuilders` helper methods and [build the aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-aggs.html) your the `AggregationBuilders` helper methods.

In your case that would go like this:

```
// build the aggregation
TermsBuilder agg = AggregationBuilders.terms("autocomplete")
        .field("autocomplete")
        .include("c.*")
        .order(Terms.Order.count(false));

// build the query
SearchResponse searchResponse2 = newClient.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setSize(0)
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("autocomplete", "c"))
        .addAggregation(agg)
        .get();
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... Seems like a valid answer to me.

Comment: Thank you, the AggregationBuilder class doesn't have any method terms( String ) in the client 1.7.3 . Do you know any alternative?

Comment: My bad, sorry, it's `AggregationBuilders` and not `AggregationBuilder` (typed too fast). I fixed the answer.

Comment: Yes, Perfect!!! Thank you!!!! I had just to had a .get() at the end:
earchResponse searchResponse2 = newClient.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setSize(0)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("autocomplete", "c"))
                .addAggregation(agg).get();